# eps file with hatch cannot be properly rendered in overleaf

Tags: eps, overleaf

I am currently writing with Overleaf and find this problem.

I am using IEEEtran.cls and when I want to insert an eps figure which is created by Matplotlib in Python, the bar chart with hatch won't be rendered.

I saved the figure with:

```
ax2.figure.savefig(save_path[0:-3]+'eps', format='eps', dpi=1000)
```

The original figure looks like this in Python

[image]

However, in Overleaf, it is rendered as

[image]

As you can see, the hatch disappeared and I have no idea why this is happening.

Would be much appreciated if anyone can help me out of this.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] This might be a previewer rendering issue. If you download the PDF and view it with Adobe Reader, does the hatches show up? If yes, then your image and PDF is fine; it's just not render-able in the Overleaf built-in previewer. If you want, you can try clicking on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel and set "Previewer" to "Native".

Comment: Hi @LianTzeLim. Thanks for your help! You solved my problem. The hatches do show up with Adobe Reader. However, after I set the 'Previewer' to Native, I can still not see the hatches in chrome, but it's ok for me since Adobe can fix this issue. Thanks again for your help :)